# Is there a way to find system locale set by user in windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, html

I am setting system locale to "German" from control panel to do localization. How do I come to know which language is set by me?
I used "window.navigator.systemLanguage" and tried "window.navigator.userLanguage" also. These variables returning "undefined" instead of returning a language set by me. Can anyone help me ?
If my system locale is US-English. Its returning "en-US" which is correct.
But why it is not returning anything for German language ?

Answer (score 2):

Try: 
`window.navigator.languages`
OR
`window.navigator.language`

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: languages returns ALL added languages on the users machine, language the default/currently selected.

Comment: I tried window.navigator.languages , it was returning [en-US, en] and when I use window.navigator.language, it returned en-US. But I changed the system locale to German. Do I need to install language pack or something to support all the languages ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I hope that the solution that I mentioned above solves your problem. If you want some languages that you don't have on your system, then you will have to install language pack. Otherwise you might have to just select that language to enable it. I hope this helps.